# JMS Queue notification before drop

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

I am using the HornetQ for jms in Jboss 5.1.0 environment. I have various queues, each has its re-delivery count and delays configured in the hornetq-configuration.xml. If the messages cannot be processed in the given retry count then they are moved into a common queue "/jms/deadqueue". An mdb of this deadqueue will process all the messages. Before moving into a deadqueue I wish to add an additional property into that message(I use ObjectMessage). Is that possible?
and also, Is it possible to get current attempted count inside the mdb onmessage method, that is, if the message is redelivered 2nd time I should get 2?

regards
V

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new book on HornetQ

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1849518408/?tag=packtpubli-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518408)